# How can I continue adding an integer with a free response textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with c#.
My goal is to be able to add an integer to a free response textbox. Allow me to explain.
I have a textbox called (Red,Green,Blue). Each color will be replaced using the Replace(); method.
Like this:

```
 private void RedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  //ActualFogColor is Result
    {

        string ActualColorFog = "game.Lighting.FogColor = Color3.new(Red,Green,Blue)";
        string Red = RedTextBox.Text;
        string FogColorRed = ActualColorFog.Replace("Red", Red);
        ActualColorFogScript.Text = FogColorRed;
}
```

This repeats for all other colors and it works fine. The problem I have is that I have a brightness button that when you click it, it adds 1 to the inputted number, but of course I had to convert it into an integer. It is basically initial + 1 = the new color. Replace Initial with new color and print that on the textbox.

Unfortunately i can't do

```
 public partial class main : Form
{
    int red = Convert.ToInt32(RedTextbox.Text); }
```

This is at the very top of the code which is why when doing this, it doesn't recognize RedTextBox.
The reason I am trying to assign the integer to the textbox is so that when the " RedTextBox.Text = '5' " It will take that 5 and add 1(by a button) which then prints the sum which I set equal to Red in `string ActualColorFog = "game.Lighting.FogColor = Color3.new(Red,Green,Blue)";`

I hope this make sense to you all, if you are confused on my plan, please leave your question.

Comment: To clarify: You Have 3 TextBoxes in which the user can input a numeric values for Red, Green and Blue. Also You have somekind of Text-Control to display `"game.Lighting.FogColor = Color3.new(Red,Green,Blue)"` where Red, Green and Blue is replaced with the numeric values provided by the user. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ackdari Yes that is exactly right. Now, I have a brightness button where when you click it, it adds 1 to the number they originally inputted and uses that sum and replaces it with red,green,blue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take one step back and think about the usability of your inputs. What I mean if you allow the user to freely enter the text, you have to tackle the input values like negative numbers, literals, numbers outside of the range (0-255 I presume), non-integer input, etc. Furthermore it would be nice if the user can use mouse scroll to increase/decrease the value. Perhaps a numeric up-down would be solution for your problem? It's not a standard control but there are enough implementations of it freely available.

Should you insist on using the text input, do the following:

- define 3 integer member variables in your code for the components.
- provide the `Changed` event handler for each textbox where you `int.TyParse` the input, check the ranges and if all goes well and update the respective member variable if it differs from the new value
- probably add mouse scroll event handler
- your button's `Click` event handler will update the member variables and the text values in the textboxes

A nicer solution would be to use the dependency properties instead of member variables, the content of the textboxes is bound to the dependency variables one way and the textboxes' `Checked` event handler does the parsing.

Comment: Would I have to use variable++; to add the number each time I click?

Comment: Yes, or rather `colourValue = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, colourValue + 1);` if your limiting range is [0, 255].

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting into that if your method is good or not but just how to solve this problem.

As i can see, ideal for you would be that you can assign `int red = Convert.ToInt32(RedTextbox.Text);` and you cannot because it is at top of your code?

It is not recognizing because that part of code is accessed before `RedTextBox` is even initialized. Solution for this is to put `int red = -1;` and then

```
public main() //Your form constructor
{
    InitializeComponents();

    // I guess you somehow add some value to RedTextbox on form
             showing so it need to be before assigning red variable

    red = Convert.ToInt32(RedTextbox.Text); //It is important to be after Initializecomponents()
}
```